# How can't I make the screen flickered?

Tags: android

I install the following app in my real mobile phone, I hope an information is displayed when I click the app icon.
But I find mobile phone screen flicker, it seems the system create and display UI, then destory UI quickly.
I don't hope the screen flicker, how can I do?  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbook.telephony" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TelephonyDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
</manifest> 


package com.androidbook.telephony;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TelephonyDemo extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        doSend(null);
    }
    public void doSend(View view) {

        try {
            sendSmsMessage(
                "12345678","Hello");
            Toast.makeText(this, "SMS Sent", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to send SMS", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void sendSmsMessage(String address,String message)throws Exception
    {
        SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using setContentView() and passing a layout as a argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its flickering because by default an Activity has a UI, and its drawing yours (since you aren't setting any, its using either pure white or pure black).  Add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" to your manifest, so it won't try to draw anything